# How can I get the response body in WSO2 ESB

Tags: json, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

The response format like this in WSO2 ESB：

```
<testresponse xmlns="http://abcd/service">
    <cookie>yummy</cookie>
    <product>YM11</product>
    <place>US</place>
</testresponse >
```

But I just want the body, how can I do?

```
 <cookie>yummy</cookie>
 <product>YM11</product>
 <place>US</place>
```

The goal is to transform the xml in a JSON object like the following

```
{
 "cookie": "yummy",
 "product": "YM11",
 "place": "US"
}
```

Comment: <cookie>yummy</cookie>
 <product>YM11</product>
 <place>US</place> 
 Is not valid, you need a "container"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the payloadFactory

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
  <format>
    <jsonObject>
      <cookie>$1</cookie>
      <product>$2</product>
      <place>$3</place>
    </jsonObject>
  </format>
  <args>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cookie"/>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//product"/>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//place"/>
  </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

But as already commented you need an enclosing element if not your xml will simply not be valid. If the goal is to output Json this element should be called jsonObject (find more info here : https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/JSON+Support).

If you don't need XML the best approach would be to directly build your json object

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
  <format>
    {
      "cookie": $1,
      "product": $2,
      "place": $3
    }
  </format>
  <args>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//cookie"/>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//product"/>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//place"/>
  </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Comment: I have already changed the payload but the response is same....

Because the response element can't remove.

If I remove the response element , the payload will change like this, the product and the place will remove:
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
 <format>                   
              <cookie>$1</cookie>         
        </format>
        <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:cookie"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:cookie"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:place"/>
        </args>
</payloadFactory>

Comment: It’s exactly what I answered initially because your xml is not valid, you cannot achieve this you need an enclosing element

Comment: I know you mean that the response element must include in payloadFactory.
But I hope I can remove the response element...do you have any idea in WSO2?
Because I want to remove xml response element  and switch json format, below is my example:

original format:
{
    "response": {
        "cookie": yummy,
        "product": "YM11",
        "place": US,
    }
}

I hope I can get the json format like this :
{
     "cookie": yummy,
     "product": "YM11",
     "place": US,
}

Thank you.

Comment: Well then I understand what you want, you should have explained this directly... I've edited my answer with 2 solutions that could fit your needs